# Correct Pronunciation of Allah in common Islamic phrases

Tags: allah, arabic, pronunciation

Let's take for example الحمد لله- The most common pronunciation is: Al-Hamdo-Li-Lah. Now, even-though there is a *Shada*/شَدّة  on the word Allah, it is not emphasized. Why is that? Another example is بسم الله - most common ways of saying do not include the emphasis of the *Shada* on Allah and is said as Bismi-lah. Why?

Comment: Interesting query, dear mate, well done for being such a curious... Good luck.

Comment: Do you speak Arabic? If so you'll realise that the mispronunciation is caused by the dialect! I'm saying this because if you hear any one speaking "Fusha" they will always place emphasis on the "Shadda"!

Comment: Yes, I'm an Arabic speaker. Even scholars pronounce it without the emphasis on the Shada. I have heard very few Mujawideen actually emphasize.

Comment: I just listened to various recitations by random reciters and they all seem to clearly pronounce the "Shadda"! Is your question concerned with pronunciation while reciting Quranic verses or within a dialect?

Comment: Can you name a reciter? I think you're confusing the "la-hi" elongated with the Alif, rather than the strong emphasis of "Laa-hi" such as when you say Allaa-h.

Comment: First a better transliteration is: al-hamdo-li-l-Lah(i) and bismi-l-Lah(i) and this is nearly how it's pronounced and therefore the emphasis (shaddah or shidah) on the lam is clear.

Comment: If you are Arabic native have you tried pronouncing them without shadah? I assume you don't know the difference because you just got used to how it is pronounced as if you pronounced it without shadah you will soon realize that the mistake or misunderstanding will be on your side! There's a big difference between al-hamdou-li-l-Lahi الْحَمْدُ لِلهِ and al-hamdo-li-Lahi الْحَمْدُ لِـلاَهِ and between bismi-l-Lahi بِسْمِ الْلَّهِ and bismi-Lahi بِسْمِ الْلاَهِ.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is taken from this source , and I will extract the general and main rule from it and format it as a short answer, for more details in Arabic get to the source

http://vb.tafsir.net/tafsir20484/

---

According to rules of Tajweed تجويد you can pronounce the (L - ل - لام) in the word Allah الله in 2 ways they are called (tafkheem تفخيم - ) and (ترقيق - tarqueeq)

- tafkheem means stress the letter and make it fat and show it. like you do when say qual Allah قَالَ الْلَّهُ
- tarqueeq means don't stress the letter and say it in a fine way. like you do when you say alhamdu lelah  الْحَمْدُ لِلهِ

The general rule that you can apply on this letter (L- ل) in the word Allah , is that if the word Allah is preceded with (a - o / fath - dam /فتح - ضم) you make tafkheem example: `qual(a) Allah - قَالَ الْلَّهُ`  as in [5:116](http://legacy.quran.com/5/116) or `muhammadon rasool(o) Allah مُحَمٌّدٌ رَسُولٌ الْلَّهِ` as in [48:29](http://legacy.quran.com/48/29)

While if it is preceded by (e / kasrah / كسرة ) you make tarqueeq, example: `L(e) llahe  لِـلَّهِ` as in [2:284](http://legacy.quran.com/2/284)

in short:

> a / o --------> tafkheem (Quala Allah / Al-Hamdo-Li-Lah)
>
> e ------------> tarqueeq (Bismi-lah)

Answer (score 0):

aww,

This is common with English speakers. English does not have a shaddah, and words with double letters are just said as if they were a single letter.

Say the words: 
letter
better
filler
comment

you will have said 
le ter
be ter
fi ler
co ment

NOT

let ter
bet ter
fil ler
com ment

since you can't say shaddahs in English, such people, when speaking Arabic, miss the shaddah out and cannot say it. That is why English speakers say "A-Lah" and not "AL-Lah".

wwb

Comment: I'm an Arabic speaker. Most recitations and common phrases only emphasis the Alif to raise the Lam. However, you will rarely hear the emphasis on the Lam itself such as when you say aLLAh. Allah is said very strongly, but Bismillah or hamdolah the Allah inside is said very weakly as if the Shadda had disappeared

Comment: @Shadi apparently you have a problem not with shadah but with the recitation (tajweed) rule of tafkheem and tarqeeq: in bismillah or al-hamdolillahi there's no tafkheem (I'm not an expert so maybe it's even here called tarqeeq) so if you find a reciter reading it with tafkheem, that means he is wrong unlesss there's an appropriate reading where this might apply (I know many but never heard one). This is also related to the fact that in these cases the word Allah is the Ism majroor. While ie. qol howa Allahu ahhad there's tafkheem on Allah. And in both cases one must recite the shidah/shadah!